# erro REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD no git push Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Estou trabalhando em um git remoto, e possuo um remoto no qual estou tentando fazer PUSH para enviar minhas novas alterações para os outros remotos (no caso unir origin/master) e mesmo enviando um `PULL` ou `Pull from upstream` na tela de PUSH fica travado na tela da imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] avançando ja trava na tela, o que quero fazer: dar um PULL, MERGE e depois enviar os meus arquivos novos com o PUSH. COmo proceder? Estou usando `NetBeans IDE 8.0 (windows).`

**EDITADO:**
o erro que da apos essa tela é esse aqui: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ai no output....

```
Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : 0000000hgfh0000fdffgg1f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
New Id        : 0000dsadda000hgfh06546f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD
Local Repository Updates
Branch Update : origin/master
Old Id        : 0000000hgfh0000fdffgg1f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
New Id        : 0000dsadda000hgfh06546f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
Result        : NOT_ATTEMPTED
==[IDE]== 24/06/2015 21:54:14 Pushing
```

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta óbvia, mas você não está conseguindo marcar o `checkbox` `[ ] master->master`?

Comment: desculpe a questao imcompleta editei, o erro é o da foto acima

Comment: Mostra esse output ai.

Comment: está ali emcima, lembrei q nao tinha posto o mesmo e editei a 1 minuto atras, rs

Comment: Rapaz, eu tive um problema desse ontem, mas no eclipse. Salva o(s) arquivo(s) que precisa de merge, apaga, baixa de novo e sobrescreve com o backup que você fez. Por mais que eu fizesse o merge e marcasse como `merged` o eclipse não entendia que o merge foi feito. As vezes pode ser o mesmo problema...